# What approach/methodology are you using for one-man software development

Tags: methodology

You can find thousands of questions out there about how you develop software and which methodology is the best one. But mainly these are targeting medium to large teams, with people having different roles and responsibilities.
What I'm interested in is what methodology are you using for your one-man-shows? What steps are you doing, what documents are you creating to get the things you want to develop clear and document it well, to share it with the community?

Especially, I’m interested in the following questions:
_Are you using a structured approach even you’re developing on your own or no at all?
_What phases are you using?
_Which documents are you writing before and after coding?

And if you have “your” standardized approach, can you share templates which you are using?

Thanks in advance,
cheers
Gerry

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about development methodologies - this is on topic for the Programmers SE. 

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it is a matter of making decisions when it comes to the development process (solo). In my case I wouldn't recommend setting up a massive development process but I would pick elements which prevent problems that I have earlier had. My approach for small applications (in the right order):

- Always write down what you are going to make and what you are not going to make (define a scope) - Think of functional requirements (Functional Design)
- ([OO only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)) Make a class diagram that displays relations between classes. (Technical Design - Sequence diagrams, while usefull, take up massive amounts of time to make)
- Write your program according to what you have just written down (or part of it).
- Refactor and redesign your application (once in every X hours, write this one down)
- Repeat step 3 to 4 until the result is what you wrote in the Functional Design.
- Walk through every corner of your application to find every single path and write this down in a testdocument. Identify possible problems in the paths and test them.

When it comes to big applications however (or assignments for someone else) I prefer using the "medium to large teams" approach. Which almost brings a guarantee that you will not be meeting most problems.